# streaming laptop webcam to wowza server with juv rtmp client

Tags: java, webcam, rtmp, wowza

I am recently doing a project to publish video to wowza server.  I am able to publish video from a file with JUV rtmp client api.  But I need to publish video from my laptop webcam directly.  How could I do that?  Please explain with an example or demo.

Main part of my code to stream video file is here:

```
final NetConnection connection = new NetConnection();

    connection.configuration().put(NetConnection.Configuration.INACTIVITY_TIMEOUT, -1);
    connection.configuration().put(NetConnection.Configuration.IO_TIMEOUT, 20 /*milliseconds*/);

    connection.addEventListener(new NetConnectionListener());

    connection.connect("rtmp://localhost:1935/live");

    try
    { 
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {/*ignore*/}
    // wait till connected

    System.out.println("then connection: "+connection.connected());
    final MediaStreamController controller = new MediaStreamController();

    final String streamFile = "C://media/JUV.FLV";

    controller.addListener(new IMediaStreamController.ListenerAdapter()
    {
        @Override
        public void onStart(final long timestamp, final IMediaStream stream)
        {
            System.out.println("onStart: " + timestamp + " " + stream);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStop(final long timestamp, final IMediaStream stream)
        {
            System.out.println("onStop: " + timestamp + " " + stream);

            if (stream != null)
            {
                stream.release();
            }

            try
            {
                controller.play(new FlvFileMediaStream(streamFile), -1 /*play the whole file*/);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onRelease(final long timestamp)
        {
            System.out.println("onRelease: " + timestamp);
        }
    });

    if (!disconnected)
    {
        NetStream stream = new NetStream(connection);

        stream.addEventListener(new NetStream.ListenerAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void onNetStatus(final INetStream source, final Map<String, Object> info)
            {
                System.out.println("NetStream#onNetStatus: " + info);

                final Object code = info.get("code");

                if (NetStream.PUBLISH_START.equals(code))
                {
                    try
                    {   System.out.println("playing: ");
                        controller.play(new FlvFileMediaStream(streamFile), -1 /*play the whole file*/);
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        stream.attachAudio(new MediaStreamMicrophone(controller));
        stream.attachCamera(new MediaStreamCamera(controller), -1);

        stream.publish("stream", NetStream.LIVE);
    }

    while (!disconnected)
    {
        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {/*ignore*/}
    }

    connection.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To stream your laptop webcam to a Wowza server, you're going to need a software application on the laptop that can encode and send the stream to the Wowza server.  There are a number of potential solutions, ranging from the open-source [`ffmpeg`](https://www.ffmpeg.org/) project to Adobe's [`Flash Media Live Encoder`](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash-media-encoder.html).

Comment: .@orde,Actually i should have previously mention that i need to do it programmatically.A java programm will do the whole things.I already publish flv video file stored on my disk.but i need to capture webcam and send the captured video to wowza server.can you help me plz???